# File fixture getting deleted after running RSpec tests

Tags: ruby, io, temporary-files

I have tests written in RSpec that have been passing up until an upgrade to Ruby 2.5.1.

The test in question has several `let` statements in a `before(:each)` block. The file that keeps getting deleted is in there like so:

```
    let(:fake_s3_file) { File.open(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../fixtures/Alexa.pdf')) }
```

Later in `before(:each)` stanza, I have this:

```
  allow(s3_client).to receive(:get_object).and_return(fake_s3_file)
  allow(Tempfile).to receive(:new).and_return(fake_s3_file)
```

It appears that in Ruby 2.5.1, my source files are getting deleted, either because of the `File.open` or the `Tempfile` reference. Has anyone run into this, and what is a good way around this? I haven't found any docs that say any changes have happened to `Tempfile` or to `File.open`. Should I copy my fixture file into a `/tmp` directory before every spec run? It seems wrong to do that, and slow.

Comment: Hey, I'd like to help but could you please provide more information such as:
1) one complete whole test suite when the file is getting deleted after it
2) Gemfile